# How to convert unicode byte sequences present in a file into corresponding unicode characters in python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, unicode

I  have a text file containing lines with unicode byte sequences. For eg. one line is:

`L'Oscar du Meilleur Film est attribu\u00e9 \u00e0 Green Book.`

In my output file, I need the above line to be written as below:

`L'Oscar du Meilleur Film est attribué à Green Book.`

How can I handle this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
s = "L'Oscar du Meilleur Film est attribu\u00e9 \u00e0 Green Book."
print s.decode('unicode_escape')
```

For writing to file it will be:

```
with open('result.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write("L'Oscar du Meilleur Film est attribu\u00e9 \u00e0 Green Book.".decode('unicode_escape').encode('utf8') + "\n")
```

Comment: Hi Tenfrow, When I write using codecs (as f.write(s.decode('unicode_escape'))), I see lot of corrupted characters written in the file. Could you share the syntax for write and not as print. many thanks

Comment: The above snippet works, but when you the below syntax for reading and writing into file is used (see below), other unicode characters get  corrupted. Here is some sample text: https://pastebin.com/iTjRHE0C. This text can be copied in a file input.txt. I am trying to do this:f=codecs.open('input.txt','r',encoding='utf-8') lines=f.readlines g= codecs.open('output.txt','w',encoding='utf-8') for line in lines: g.write(line.decode('unicode_escape').encode('utf-8')...This leads to corruption of characters. Instead, is there anything else I can try?

Comment: @espeed, what do you mean by "corrupted"?

Comment: Hi Tenfrow, See here:https://pastebin.com/WrG6yuKV   so the text at  pastebin.com/iTjRHE0C when pasted in a file and is read and written using codecs (encoding=utf-8), the output is seen as here: https://pastebin.com/WrG6yuKV. While writing , I am using the syntax: for line in f.readlines(): g.write(line.decode('unicode_escape').encode('utf8')).